# OAuth Redirect URI and http.client

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, http.client

I want to connect to an API which is using OAuth 2.0. It requires OAuth Redirect URI which is defined as:
"The URL authenticated OAuth flows for this application should be redirected to."
From this definition, I understand that it should be 'my computer'.

I am using Python 3.9 and I send GET request to the API using http.client module.
So, what is the address of this http.client that I can type as OAuth Redirect URI?

Should I define host and port using Socket module?

I tried localhost:8000 for the OAuth Redirect URI, but then it seemed irrational, also not worked. I have googled it but I am confused as hell due to the client, host, server definitions.

I also tried no-ip.com free hostnames to type to the Redirect URI but I couldn't manage to get it work..

Comment: What kind of app did you develop? Desktop app otrHttp app? In the 2nd case, you need uri redirect otherwise you must change the oauth2 flow. I suggest you read about [oauth2](https://oauth.net/2/) and try different flow with this [playground](https://www.oauth.com/playground/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response; it is HTTP app..I have a db, and before login to db, I wanted to authorize & confirm the user id. It is harder than it seems :(